# I have a problem with using python-telegram-bot run_polling()

Tags: python, bots, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to learn coding telegram bots using PTB.
There is a problem with running the first tutorial code:

```
    from telegram import Update
    from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, ContextTypes

    async def hello(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
        await update.message.reply_text(f'Hello {update.effective_user.first_name}')
    
    app = ApplicationBuilder().token("****").build()
    app.add_handler(CommandHandler("hello", hello))
    app.run_polling()
```

after running the code I got the error:

```
RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop
```

would you please guide me?
Thanks.

Comment: which python version, PTB version and operating system are you using? What's the full traceback of the error?

Comment: did you follow this:   https://python-telegram-bot.org  ?  (it looks like the code is from here).